# VBS Script Spaces in File Path

Tags: vbscript, whitespace, filepath

I have a vbscript file with the following line of code:

```
addToArray arrScenarios, "Scenarios\BFTB Scenarios\Tutorial.cos"
```

When I run it, it cannot find the `Tutorial.cos` file. 
However, if I change the '`BFTB Scenarios`' directory name by eliminating the space it runs fine:

```
addToArray arrScenarios, "Scenarios\BFTBScenarios\Tutorial.cos"
```

I have read the similar questions on this subject and tried to replicate their advice by putting double quotes around the entire path but to no avail:

```
addToArray arrScenarios, ""Scenarios\BFTB Scenarios\Tutorial.cos""
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: _When I run it, it cannot find the Tutorial.cos file._ Can you clarify what that means? How are you "running it" - you haven't showed the code that tries to open the file location.

Answer (score -1):

What doesn't work?

```
option explicit

Dim   arrScenarios()
Redim arrScenarios(-1)

addToArray arrScenarios, "simple_string_without_spaces"
addToArray arrScenarios, "any string containing spaces"
addToArray arrScenarios, """any string in double quotes"""
addToArray arrScenarios, chr(34) & "yna string in double quotes" & chr(34)

    Sub AddToArray( vArray, Item)
        Redim Preserve vArray(UBound(vArray)+1)
                       vArray(UBound(vArray))=Item
    End Sub

Dim ii
For ii = 0 To UBound(arrScenarios)
    Wscript.Echo "arrScenarios(" & CStr( ii) & ") = " & arrScenarios( ii)
Next
```

**Output**:

```
==>cscript \VB_scripts\SO\30317733.vbs
arrScenarios(0) = simple_string_without_spaces
arrScenarios(1) = any string containing spaces
arrScenarios(2) = "any string in double quotes"
arrScenarios(3) = "yna string in double quotes"
```

**Original answer**:

I can guess only which way the 2nd parameter is processed in the `addToArray` subroutine, but try double all *inner* double quotes as follows:

```
addToArray arrScenarios, """Scenarios\BFTB Scenarios\Tutorial.cos"""
```

or add leading and trailing ones in this way:

```
addToArray arrScenarios, chr(34) & "Scenarios\BFTB Scenarios\Tutorial.cos" & chr(34)
```

Comment: This is the AddToArray function:

Sub AddToArray(vArray, Item)
 Redim Preserve vArray(UBound(vArray)+1)
 vArray(UBound(vArray))=Item
End Sub

Comment: Neither does the other one. Tough little blighter isn't it?